# Dovecot: Kill permission denied when reloading

Tags: linux, docker, dovecot, process

### The problem

I want to run a Dovecot server inside a docker on my server. The daemon process starts successfully, but whenever I try to reload the configuration, restart, or stop the daemon I get the following error:

`start-stop-daemon: warning: failed to kill X: Permission denied`

Where X is the PID of the dovecot process. I have been unsuccessful in trying to find anything that comes close to the error I get.

### More about the environment

I run the process inside a docker container based on the following linux version:

`Linux 3b71bd992d42 4.10.0-21-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 28 16:14:22 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

The docker image is defined by the Dockerfile in https://github.com/tomav/docker-mailserver.

My dovecot local config looks something like

```
disable_plaintext_auth = no
mail_privileged_group = mail
log_path = /var/log/dovecot.log
mail_location = mbox:/var/mail/%u
userdb {
      driver = passwd
}
passdb {
      args = %s
        driver = pam
}
protocols = " imap"

protocol imap {
      mail_plugins = " autocreate"
}
plugin {
      autocreate = Trash
        autocreate2 = Sent
          autosubscribe = Trash
            autosubscribe2 = Sent
}

service auth {
      unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
      group = postfix
      mode = 0660
      user = postfix
      }
}

ssl=required
ssl_cert = < my pem certificate
ssl_key = < my private key
```

Running dovecot with either `/usr/sbin/dovecot -c myconfig` or `service dovecot start` gives the same error when I run either `/usr/sbin/dovecot reload` or `service dovecot stop/restart`

### More information on what I've tried

The way I see it, when reloading/restarting/stopping, dovecot tries to kill the running process, and in this case fails to do so. The first thing I tried was to kill manually this process, as root. Which gives me the same error... So then I checked the state of the process. A simple ps aux tells me that the dovecot process is in the Ss state.

```
root         1  0.0  0.0  18244  3380 ?        Ss   08:47   0:00 /bin/bash
root        32  0.0  0.0  18036  2656 ?        Ss   08:47   0:00 /usr/sbin/dovecot -c /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
dovecot     34  0.0  0.0   9520  1012 ?        S    08:47   0:00 dovecot/anvil
root        35  0.0  0.0   9652  1056 ?        S    08:47   0:00 dovecot/log
root        37  0.0  0.0  25300  4036 ?        S    08:47   0:00 dovecot/config
root        64  0.0  0.0  34424  2884 ?        R+   08:57   0:00 ps aux
```

I tried to see with strace what the blocking call was, but unfortunately got

```
root@3b71bd992d42:/# strace -d -p 32
strace: new tcb for pid 32, active tcbs:1
strace: ptrace_setoptions = 0x11
strace: PTRACE_SEIZE doesn't work
```

Another error on which I don't have anymore clue.

`pstree` gives me

```
bash-+-dovecot-+-anvil
     |         |-config
     |         `-log
     `-pstree
```

I am a bit taken aback by all that, I don't really have any idea about what to do next, beside trying a completely different image than docker-mailserver with a fresh install of dovecot and see if that fixes the error. But this is something I would like to avoid. It is not the first time I run a dovecot server, but I've never got something like that.

Comment: This does not really answer your question at all and might even contain a bit of ranting, but the project's way of putting a whole mail server stack in a single Docker container is pretty much against any best practices existing.

Comment: No ranting, this is interesting. Do you care to elaborate? Would you rather have the components splitted up accross containers. One for postfix, one for dovecot etc...? That would be my long term goal, I don't have all the time I would like to dedicate to this project, I wanted to patch together a containeurized mail server that works. But I am also very interested in the best practices, so if could enlighten me, I'm all for it!

Comment: The idea behind containers is building microservices: one job, one container. Small and well-seperated jobs make maintenance easy, unlike such a large and clumpy all-in-one-box which you will never be able to decompose again. Some people say "one daemon per container", which seems a little bit tight, there might well be valid use cases for more than one -- but not putting together about a dozen of components performing _very_ different jobs. Furthermore, the project is breaking quite a number of additional Docker best practices -- I haven't looked in mail-related best practices yet.

Comment: Actually, I'm migrating all my own mail stuff to containers right now, but not sure whether I will provide some documentation (this multiplies the effort). But I am _very_ sure that on the long term this will save time and result in a more robust setup.

Comment: Yes I agree with your view. This project had the merit of convenience. Since I only really cared about the dovecot and postfix part, I thought that putting them in the same container wouldn't seem too far-fetched, and certainly less overkill than running a single instance for each of them. That being said, I seems to me that the issue I raise denotes more of an incompatibility issue between the linux 4.10 kernel image and docker 17.05-ce, since this error doesn't come up with Linux 4.4. Anyway thanks for the reply, and if you come up with some doc I'd be happy to read it!